# Selenium Webdriver Python code explanation needed

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Please provide me some basic idea about the code. I am new to Python. I went through some tutorials and everything is related to Selenium JAVA where they mention webdriver as an Interface, whereas in Python webdriver is called as Module.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("../drivers/chromedriver.exe")
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
driver.get("https://google.com")
driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("Automation step by step")
driver.find_element_by_name("btnK").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.close()
driver.quit()
print("Test Completed")
```

As per my understanding, we are importing webdriver module from the selenium package. We created an Object called driver.

Is Chrome a class of Webdriver Module? Are we creating an object of Chrome using driver = webdriver.chrome() ?

I used Pycharm and tried to check what is happening inside Chrome class and Get method. But I didn't it clearly. Is Chrome Class defined in the Webdriver Module? I am confused if the methods used in the above codes are Webdriver methods or Chrome Class methods.

Comment: Hope you have gone through this https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import time`  # imports time module to add sleep()
from selenium import webdriver  # Importing Selenium webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("../drivers/chromedriver.exe")  # path to local ChromeDriver  
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)  # set timeout for a page to load
driver.get("https://google.com")  # Goes to Google site
driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("Automation step by step")  # Finds search field by name attribute and sends text there with send_keys() method
driver.find_element_by_name("btnK").click()  # finds button by name attribute and clicks it
time.sleep(2)  # same as Thread.sleep(), but values are in seconds
driver.close()  # closing the window that is in focus
driver.quit()  # exiting browser
print("Test Completed")  # analogue to System.out.println() in Java
```

Selenium for Python has really good docs. Check here https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html

Comment: I understood what that code is doing. Please read my question. I am having understanding about modules, classes and what is happening inside exactly.

Comment: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started Read here. Namely, this part The ChromeDriver class starts the ChromeDriver server process at creation and terminates it when quit is called.

Comment: The concept of ChromeDriver is the same.